# How to get spring properties from application.yml file in @BeforeClass method when testing

Tags: spring, junit

Because `@BeforeClass` method in Junit should be static and static methods couldn't access instance objects, I couldn't use the following code to get spring properties.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

OR

```
@Value("${spring.path}")
private String path;
```

Are there other ways to access spring properties from `application.yml` in `@BeforeClass` method of Spring Junit Test?

```
@BeforeClass
public static void test() {
    // I want to access path or env variable here.
    // Generally, it's impossible to access instance variables in static method
    // So my question is how to access spring properties from here.

    // In the case, I'd like to copy a file to spring.path folder for testing.
}
```

Comment: is not a SpringBoot application?

Comment: It's a springboot application

Comment: whats your use-case?

Comment: In fact, I'd like to copy a file to `spring.path` folder once before running each test case. Because this file will be used in these test cases.

Comment: if you reset your file once (and not for each test), it means that your tests are not unitary. This is a problem if your tests depend on one another. You need use `@Before` (instead of `@BeforeClass`). Is it important for good practice.

Comment: @sgrillon All test cases depend on that file and just read information from it. So copying this file once is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@Before` (instead of `@BeforeClass`)

**java test file:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SofTests {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${spring.path}")
    private String path;

    @Before
    public void sof() {
        System.out.println("sof) path: " + path);
    }

}
```

**src/test/resources/application.yml file:**

```
spring.path: foo/file.ext
```

**Console:**

```
sof) path: foo/file.ext
```

Comment: I'd like to access spring properties in `@beforeclass` method of JUNIT test class.

Comment: @niaomingjian, I changed my response with a springbooot solution

Comment: I know `@Before` is a workaround. But what I focused on is `@beforeclass`.

Comment: with `@BeforeClass` do not work because is it before Spring cycle. So `@Before` is after Spring cycle and before your test action.

Comment: Junit seems to work as you said. Could you give me a link which explains the calling order about them?

Comment: @niaomingjian, I modified my answer with the right solution (+ good explanations) You had voted negatively my answer, can you modify by a "plus" please because all peoples will think that the answer is not good.